# Bootstrap Multiselect with 'No search Result message'

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap multi-select with searching enabled. Everything works well. Issue is when user searches for a string which is not present in the drop down option then the it is not showing any message to user saying like 'No result found'. The blank drop down gets shown.

How can I show the 'no result found message' if search string does not match any drop down value.

Here is the code :

```
$('#mydropdown').multiselect({
      buttonWidth: '80%',
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      onChange: function(option, checked, select){
          setValue();
      }
});
```

Thanks,
Tushar

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Answer (score 0):

For the current version of bootstrap-multiselect I made the following changes to the bootstrap-multiselect.js file. While I hate to edit source files, the no results message was a requirement by the client.

Place this code above "buildFilter: function()":

```
_$customNoResultsLi: null,
_toggleCustomNoResults: function () {
    if (this._$customNoResultsLi === null) {
        this._$customNoResultsLi = $('<li class="customNoResults">No Search Results</li>')
            .appendTo(this.$ul);
    }
    if (this.$ul.find('li:not(.filter-hidden) input[type="checkbox"]').length == 0) {
        this._$customNoResultsLi.show();
    } else {
        this._$customNoResultsLi.hide();
    }
},
```

Then within buildFilter(), I add the following right before "this.updateSelectAll();":

```
//CUSTOM CODE
this._toggleCustomNoResults();
```

Essentially this code will add a "No Results" message when all checkboxes are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This external code provides "no result match " with search key word

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".multiselect-search", function (e) {

    var thisObj = this;

    setTimeout(function () {

        if ($(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find("li.multi-no-results").length == 0)
            $(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().append('<li style="display:none" class="multi-no-results cropin-multi-select-noresult-lable"><a  href="#">No results matched ""</a></li>');

        var totalOptions = $(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings().last().find("option").length;
        var totalFilteredOptins = totalOptions - $(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find("li.filter-hidden").length;

        if (totalFilteredOptins <= 0) {
            $(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find("li.multi-no-results").find("a").text('No results matched "' + $(thisObj).val() + '"');
            $(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find("li.multi-no-results").show();
        }
        else {
            $(thisObj).parent().parent().parent().find("li.multi-no-results").hide();
        }

    }, 300);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for new version 2 , in the bootstrap-multiselect.js js file buildFilter function, place below code and design it with css.Image for correct place

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAEQC.png)

```
 if ($('input[value!="' + this.options.selectAllValue + '"] 
 [type="checkbox"]:visible', this.$ul).length == 0) {
 $(".multiselect-all").hide();
 $(".multiselect-container").append('<div class="multi_not_found 
 multiselect-option"><label class="form-check-label">No result 
 found</label></div>');
 }
 else {
 $(".multi_not_found").remove();
  $(".multiselect-all").show();
}
```